# NSPredicate raises 'Unknown number type or nil passed to arithmetic function expression.' in QuickLook plugin

Tags: cocoa, nspredicate, quicklook

I have an NSArray of NSDictionary. All the dictionaries have a key `image-path`.
I want to get a filtered array of only the dictionaries that match a given value (content of my `path` variable) for the key `image-path`.

I validated the structure of the data I have using this line (it prints me all the values of the dictionaries for the key image-path):

```
NSLog(@"array key paths: %@", [mountedImages valueForKeyPath:@"image-path"]);
```

I am using this code:

```
NSString *path = @"value-I-want-to-match";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(image-path LIKE[cd] \"%@\")", path];
NSArray *filteredArray = nil;
filteredArray = [mountedImages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The last line crashes and produces the following error:

```
[ERROR] Computing 6571367.19831142 raised 'Unknown number type or nil passed to arithmetic function expression.'
```

I am doing this in a QuickLook plugin. I can step-through my code with gdb, but I don't seem to get any trace. I only get:

```
[...]
[ERROR] Computing 6571367.19831142 raised 'Unknown number type or nil passed to arithmetic function expression.'
[Switching to process 23335 thread 0x8903]
[Switching to process 23335 thread 0xa703]
[Switching to process 23335 thread 0x8903]
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the escaped quotes you placed in your predicate format string. As documented in the Apple predicate format string reference:

> When string variables are substituted into a format string using %@ , they are surrounded by
>   quotation marks. If you want to specify a dynamic property name, use %K in the format
>   string, as shown in the following example.
>
> ```
>  NSString *attributeName = @"firstName";
>  NSString *attributeValue = @"Adam";
>  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@", attributeName, attributeValue];
> ```
>
> The predicate format string in this case evaluates to firstName like "Adam".
>
> Single or double quoting variables (or substitution variable strings) cause %@, %K, or
>   $variable to be interpreted as a literal in the format string and so prevent any
>   substitution. In the following example, the predicate format string evaluates to firstName
>   like "%@" (note the single quotes around %@).
>
> ```
>  NSString *attributeName = @"firstName";
>  NSString *attributeValue = @"Adam";
>  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like '%@'", attributeName, attributeValue];
> ```

In your case, your predicate is being created as `image-path LIKE[cd] "%@"`, which fails to evaluate correctly when used to filter your array.